# Self Hosting Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, hosting

I would like to host my own chrome extension somewhere other than the chrome web store. I plan to install this on a device via the windows registry. How do I host this extension on my own server?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Google has prevented us from doing this on Windows and OS X.  It used to be the case that we could just deploy a CRX file.  Now, this is only possible on Linux.  I do think you can specify an extension ID in a Windows Group Policy, but the extension still has to go through the store.

Comment: I experienced this behaviour when trying to host my extension on a web server or as local crx file. Is there any official source / statement from Google confirming this?